# How to reorder list elements in unordered list using keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, wai-aria

I am trying to reorder list items using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to change the order in list in JavaScript. Please see code below:

```
<ul>
<li tabindex="0">item one </li>
<li tabindex="0">item two </li>
<li tabindex="0">item three </li>
<li tabindex="0">item four </li> 
</ul>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have tried with document.activeElement based on that i am trying to change the li element in unordered list

Comment: what about this simple solution: http://codepen.io/sp90/pen/OPKbVG?editors=101

Comment: If the order of the items matters, then you should use an ordered list, not an unordered list in order to have semantic markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$('li').keydown(function(e) {
  var li= $(this);
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    switch(e.which) {
      case 38: li.insertBefore(li.prev()); break; //up
      case 40: li.insertAfter(li.next());  break; //down
    }
    li.focus();
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fs6ah0um/)

Comment: That's tricky, because the space bar isn't a special key like `Ctrl`, `Alt`, or `Shift`.  That may be worth posting as a new question.

Comment: Now i am  posting this as a question

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
$(li1).detach().insertAfter(li2);
```

or

```
$(li1).detach().insertBefore(li2);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code with Jquery:
This example uses the up arrow (38).
To use the 'down' arrow, replace the 38 with 40 (in my chrome, the down arrow opens some extension function):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 38){//check if ctrl key is pressed
        var lis = $('ul > li'); //get all li's

        //order the li's
        not_ordered = new Array();
        for(i=0; i < lis.length; i++){
            not_ordered.push(lis[i].innerText);
        }
        ordered = not_ordered.sort();
        //rebuild the li's with new order:
        var new_ul_content = '';
        for(i=0; i < ordered.length; i++){
            new_ul_content += '<li tabindex="0">' + ordered[i] + ' </li>';
        }
        //replace ul content with new content:
        $('ul')[0].innerHTML = new_ul_content;
    }

});
```

});